# Question on Intro to Computer Science quiz

Tags: java

[image: Java question that baffles me]

I recently came across this question on the Saylor Academy intro to CS quiz. It’s about the syntax in Java. Could someone please explain what I’m missing?

Compiler says I am correct.

Comment: They're wrong. `int x += 1` is not legal Java code. It has never been legal Java code. Now if it was `int x =+ 1` that would be a nicely tricky question, and the answer would be `a`; so my guess is they have a typo in their trick question. Shame on them.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. The question is improperly formulated. You can't run it if there is a compilation error, and they haven't allowed for that possibility even existing, let alone being correct. They also haven't specified the context: the result could conceivably be different as between instance members and local variables.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you!  wow, I’m sure that’s what they were trying to do. All their questions seem to be attempting to be trick questions. I had no idea about the =+ 1 though, so glad this happened.

Comment: It's just `x=+1` to the compiler, the whitespace isn't significant. And `+1` is a unary positive one. So just `1`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch right, so it would be similar for int x = -1;

Comment: The tricky way to write it would be `int x =- 1`, but yes.

Comment: Even if it were `int x =+ 1`, there wouldn't be a "result" here. It's not an expression, it's a variable declaration statement. The "result" would be the declaration of a variable.

Comment: yes ,the given question has some mistake.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 3):

That is a blatant mistake on their part. I do not think any Java version accepts this code - i.e., this is a compilation error and your answer is correct. You can run it anywhere to verify this:

```
>cat test.java
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        int x+= 1;
    }
}
>java test.java
test.java:3: error: ';' expected
        int x+= 1;
             ^
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

Answer (score -5):

Its true when the value of x is set during variable declaration the expression above will not  result into an error the code below explains it better

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int x = 5;
        x  += 1;
        System.out.println(x);
        //the value of x would be six ie original value of x plus 1
     }
}
```

Comment: That's not the code from the question, so it doesn't show the result of running the code in the question.